# Join thread for multiple times

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I need to make a program which create 2 threads which will print 10 times their id (pthread_self), but make that you printed IDs alternation (A, B, A, B, ...).
The problem is how i can make, i was thinking maybe i can join every thread 10 times, but i get error...
Any idea, thanks.
Here is a code what i maked... :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static pthread_mutex_t my_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void * rutina (void *param)
{

 int * cuv=  (int *) param;
  int j;
  pthread_mutex_lock (&my_mutex);
  printf("cuv: %d",*cuv);
  pthread_mutex_unlock (&my_mutex);
}

main ()
{
  int i;
  pthread_t th[2];
  int* argc;
  argc=malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        *argc=i;
        pthread_create (&th[i], NULL, rutina, argc);
    }



  for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    pthread_join (th[i], NULL);
}
```

Comment: *The problem is how i can make, i think i can join every proccess 10 times, but i get error, because it's not posible...* Please clarify your problem and question.

Comment: Sorry for that, we just maked proccess and threads in same time...

Comment: I'm quite sure, you're only supposed to 'join' every thread once. Joining is basically waiting for that thread to finish.

Comment: Still confusing; what is preventing you from running the code in main 10 times in a loop?

Comment: @self. This looks like an assignment. Anyway, questioning the origin of the question won't help the OP getting an answer to the actual question.

Comment: I dont't know how to make an alternation in 'rutina', and print like this A, B, A, B... If i join threads, will print AAAAA... BBBBB...

Comment: You should not join the threads, the reason being is that Joining a thread means that you are waiting for it to finish. You should detach the first one and then join the second one(to prevent main from exiting).

Comment: In case it isn't clear enough from other comments, once you successfully join a thread, that thread no longer exists...